# Restrict users from storing in home directory in Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, rstudio-server

We have a RHEL server where multiple users have access to it through application. Application RStudio running on these servers default the workspace to the users /home folder. Though there is separate space provided for individual users, users tend to store the files onto /home filling up the /home.

Is there any possibility to restrict users from storing data to their home folders either at server level or R Studio level which would force them to use the provided location?

Though there are options to change the default workspace for all the users, due to the large number of teams each having their sensitive data, it is not possible to have a shared folder as default location.

Comment: This is a system administration question, not a programming question.  It is off-topic on SO, but it would probably be appropriate for [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, posted it in the provided forum.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a group without write permissions on home folder and start rstudio through the command sg, which allows you to start it with the group id with reduced permissions.

The ls -l command displays directory contents in long format. The long format contains both permissions and ownership.

```
# ls -l
```

With chown you can change owner and group associated to a file/directory (-R == recursive)

```
# sudo chown -R user01:groupA Directory
```

By setting the owner and the single group, the others will have restrictions (if set) in accessing files / folders.
The chmod command is used to modify the various permissions/restrictions.

```
# sudo chmod -c ug=rwx,o= file1
```

going specifically

```
-c == report if the change is made
u == user
g == group
rwx == read, write, execute
o == others
=null == no permission
```

For create a new group you can use groupadd

```
# sudo groupadd rstudiogroup
```

You will have to set the new group created as the owner of the save destination folder and finally start the software through the command sg

```
# sudo sg rstudiogroup -c rstudio
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.